# SceneKit physics contact method crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, exc-bad-access

In a SceneKit project, the following method is *intermittently* (but consistently) crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Specifically, it says `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`.

```
contactTestBetween(_:_:options:)
```

The method is called from inside SceneKit's `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` method. It's also being run on the main thread because otherwise, this code crashes even more often. So, here's the greater context:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    var ball = self.scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ball", recursively: true)
    var ballToFloorContact: [SCNPhysicsContact]?
    let theNodes: [SCNNode]? = self.scene?.rootNode.childNodes.filter({ $0.name?.contains("floor") == true})
    let optionalWorld: SCNPhysicsWorld? = self.scene?.physicsWorld

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let allNodes = theNodes {
            for i in 0..<allNodes.count {
                let n = allNodes[i]

                if let b = n.physicsBody, let s = ball?.physicsBody {
                    ballToFloorContact = optionalWorld?.contactTestBetween(b, s)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` is set in `viewDidLoad`:

```
scnView.delegate = scnView
```

**Additional info:**

1. When the crash occurs, `optionalWorld`, `b`, and `s` are all properly defined.
2. I originally had the call to `filter` located *inside* the `DispatchQueue`, but it was causing a crash that seemed identical to this one. Moving that line *outside* the `DispatchQueue` solved that problem.

**Question: Any idea what might be causing this crash, and how I might avoid it? Am I doing something wrong, here?**

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:** I tried adding the following `guard` statement to protect against a situation where the `contactTestBetween` method is, itself, nil (after all, that seems to be what Xcode is telling me):

```
guard let optionalContactMethod = optionalWorld?.contactTestBetween else {
    return
}
```

However, after some additional testing time, `contactTestBetween` eventually crashed once again with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the line `guard let optionalContactMethod = optionalWorld?.contactTestBetween else {`. I truly do not understand how that could be, but it be. Note that I tried this `guard` paradigm both *with* and *without* the presence of the `DispatchQueue.main.async` call, with the same result.

Comment: what happens, if you do not use at all the DispatchQueue?

Comment: Without the DispatchQueue, it crashes more often.

Comment: which line of the code is causing the crash? it should be indicated red in xcode

Comment: It's the `ballToFloorContact = optionalWorld?.contactTestBetween(b, s)` line that crashes. Specifically, it is the call to `contactTestBetween()`.

Comment: could you try a guard statement to check, if any of your values could be nil? and if it's nil just exit the function with return?

Comment: When the crash occurs, `optionalWorld`, `b`, and `s` are all properly defined, according to Xcode. I believe that's all the relevant ones. But, more to the point, I think a `guard` statement would be redundant here because I'm already doing `if let b = n.physicsBody, let s = ball?.physicsBody {` and also `optionalWorld?`. So, checking those values again with a `guard` statement probably wouldn't help.

Comment: On second thought, I'm actually going to use a `guard` statement to check if `contactTestBetween`, itself, is `nil`. I'll report back when I get some results.

Comment: @ZAY So, I set up a `guard` statement that returns if `optionalWorld?.contactTestBetween` is nil. But it actually crashed on that line! I tried it both with and without the DispatchQueue closure, and it crashed both ways. I truly do not understand this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I did two things, here:

1. I added `Accelerometer` and `Gyroscope` to the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in my `Info.plist` file. I did this because my game uses `Core Motion`, but I had neglected to include the necessary values.
2. On a hunch, I replaced the `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` method `renderer(_: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime: TimeInterval)` with the alternative method `renderer(_: SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene: SCNScene, atTime: TimeInterval)`.

Since doing these things, I haven't been able to reproduce a crash.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative unsafe fix is

```swift
try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1)
```

somewhere before invoking `contactTestBetween()`.

This answer sits here as a warning to anyone who might want to use async/await as a fix or is inadvertendly using some await (any kind of await works) to break out of the run loop which somehow makes debugging `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` nearly impossible because it will get triggered rarely enough.

I know from experience that if the above fixed a race then races **WILL** still happen especially and mostly with CPUs running at 100% and actually I got `contactTestBetween` to crash once after many tries.

I have no clue what's going on behind the scenes or how to synchronize with `physicsWorld`.

@West1 solution is still the best if it works as advertised.